# Deleting all IPs on an interface with iproute2

Tags: iproute2

I have an interface that I setup like this

```
ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev eth0
ip addr add 192.168.1.2/24 dev eth0
ip addr add 192.168.1.3/24 dev eth0
```

etc.

Is there an easy way to delete all of the IPs I add with out doing

```
ip addr del 192.168.1.1/24 dev eth0
ip addr del 192.168.1.2/24 dev eth0
ip addr del 192.168.1.3/24 dev eth0
```

or doing something like

```
ips=`ip addr show dev eth0 | grep -oe '192\.168\1\.[0-2][0-9]{1,2}'`
for ii in $ips; do
   ip addr del $ii dev eth0
done
```

There must be a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: that regex has a lot of problems, but I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: what's wrong with this question?

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/153559/how-can-i-clear-the-ip-address-of-ethernet-interface-without-cycling-the-interfa

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does the flush command not do what you want

```
ip addr flush eth0
```

Comment: yes it does, I must have missed it in the man page...

Comment: Interesting for me that there is really no need to put `dev` before iface name (`eth0`).